# How to perform mathematical operation which is stored as character in R?

Tags: r, regex

I have a table like this,

```
structure(list(component = structure(1:4, .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d"), class = "factor"), dimension = structure(c(1L, 3L, 
4L, 2L), .Label = c("12*10*05", "30*30*20(2)+32*34*04", "30*30*20+174*153*21+108*014*04", 
"98*98*12(2)"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I need to perform mathematical operation in column 'dimension' which is stored as character and convert to integer. For ex: `"98*98*12(2)"` should be stored as a result of `=(98*98*12)*2 = 230496`

The desired output:

```
structure(list(component = structure(1:4, .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d"), class = "factor"), dimension = c(600L, 583110L, 230496L, 
40352L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Use `gsub` to insert `*` between a parenthesis and the preceding or following number or parenthesis. When you have valid syntax, `parse` and `eval`uate.

Comment: Also, if security is a potential issue, you should sanitize the input (e.g., ensure that it contains no alphabetic characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
> within(df, new.dimension <- sapply(gsub("(\\d)\\(","\\1*(",dimension),function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))) 
  component                      dimension new.dimension
1         a                       12*10*05           600
2         b 30*30*20+174*153*21+108*014*04        583110
3         c                    98*98*12(2)        230496
4         d           30*30*20(2)+32*34*04         40352
```

Comment: The gsub should perhaps check for number / space before `(`, because `gsub("\\(","*(","1+(2+3)")` gives "1+*(2+3)", which can't be evaluated

Comment: @Waldi Thanks for your comments, I guess now it is fixed